# API for Bayesian networks with Java

Tags: java, bayesian-networks

Is there any API for building bayesian networks of influence diagram with java?

Comment: bayesian networks OR influence diagrams, you mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found two influence diagram engines with Java API which are free & open source:

http://genie.sis.pitt.edu/

> SMILE (Structural Modeling, Inference, and Learning Engine) is a fully
>   portable library of C++ classes implementing graphical
>   decision-theoretic methods, such as Bayesian net-works and influence
>   diagrams, directly amenable to inclusion in intelligent systems.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/unbbayes/

> UnBBayes is a probabilistic network framework written in Java. It has
>   both a GUI and an API with inference, sampling, learning and
>   evaluation. It supports BN, ID, MSBN, OOBN, HBN, MEBN/PR-OWL, PRM,
>   structure, parameter and incremental learning.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Jayes](http://www.eclipse.org/recommenders/jayes/) website:

> ### What Jayes is, and what it isn't
>
> [Jayes](http://www.eclipse.org/recommenders/jayes/) is a Java library for Bayesian networks and the inference in such networks. At the moment, there is no learning component included. (We can, however, recommend the [Apache Mahout](http://mahout.apache.org/) library.)

Answer (score 0):

It's not free, but Norsys Netica has a Java API.
It's not pretty, either.

http://www.norsys.com/netica-j.html