# Most performant Bayesian Network Java API available?

Tags: java, bayesian-networks

I'm currently planning the implementation of a bayesian network solution for inference of outcome probabilities given known node networks, in a Java application. I've been looking around the web for what Java APIs are available, and have come across a number of these – [jSMILE](http://www.bayesfusion.com/smile-engine), [AgenaRisk](http://www.agenarisk.com/), JavaBayes, netica-J, Jayes, WEKA(?), etc.

Now, I'm struggling to find any good comparison of/compare all these APIs in terms of performance, usability and price for commercial applications, to know which one is the best to go for. I have tested out the AgenaRisk API, which suited my needs however before committing to this product it'd be great to hear if anyone has any knowledge of:

1. variation in performance between different APIs (or is it negligible? i.e. they all rely on identical fundamental Bayesian calculations?)
2. robust free alternatives to AgenaRisk?
3. does it matter if one of these solutions seems to no longer be supported/relies on a very old version of Java (e.g. JavaBayes is on Java 1.1 I believe)?
4. (Bonus points) are Bayesian Networks and Bayesian Network Classifications one and the same thing? As for example WEKA advertises itself as providing the latter.
5. List item

The [last post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298739/api-for-bayesian-networks-with-java) on here looking for a good solution was from 2012, so I'm wondering if anyone would recommend any new solutions which have emmerged or if it's still a good bet to work with those.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well for anyone who comes across this and is interested:

1. Will be figuring this out myself soon and will update this (If I forget nudge me).
2. Jayes seems to do everything AgenaRisk does if you're simply creating a graph and want to get some beliefs out of it, minus the GUI. Also it seems there you can choose what algorithm to use, which I haven't seen with AgenaRisk.
3. I'm going to stick to current solutions to be safe
4. ...yes they are

Comment: I'm not sure what *yes there are* means as an answer to *are … the same as …* but the answer to 4 is not exactly: WEKA, for example, can learn a Bayesian network and use it for classification but cannot (according to the docs) use it for inference.

Comment: Hi nekomatic, this was my initial understanding also but it turns out you can in fact perform inference alone on a predefined bayesian network, it's just a little awkward to do (I have been able to reproduce results achieved using Jayes or AgenaRisk). I will be building classes on top the WEKA library for my purpose to clean up this process. Apologies if I'm misunderstanding something though

Comment: That's very interesting, is it something you're able to share any more detail or examples of?

Comment: Of course: the class `weka.classifiers.bayes.net.BayesNetGenerator` will let you create nodes, add states/values, link them (using arcs in WEKA) and set distributions. Then you can use `weka.classifiers.bayes.net.MarginCalculator` to perform the inference. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks. It'll take me a while to figure out whether or not that meets my needs but it's given me something to go on.